# How to solve "__construct() must be an instance" error in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5.7

I am facing an error. But i don't know how to solve this.Someone please help me.I am providing code bellow:

```
   **Controller.php**

    public function store(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required|max:255',
    'content' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user = Auth::user();

   $single_post = $user->posts()->create([
   'title' => $request->title,
   'content' => $request->content,
   'published' => $request->has('published')
   ]);

    $post = Post::all();

    broadcast(new ViewPost($post))->toOthers();
    return back();
    }


    **ViewPost.php**

     public function __construct(Post $post)
     {
     $this->post = $post;
     }
```

Here is Error:[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SpEH.png)

Comment: error says it is expecting a `Post` object as argument but you are pass a collection into it. So the problem probably comes from `$post = Post::all();`  You might want to check out the return type of `Post::all()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please do the private varibale of $post and then pass it on constructor just like that 
in that first use its model.

```
use App\Post;

class xyz {
 private $post;
 public function __construct(Post $post){
   $this->post = $post;
 }
}
```

Just like that and try it once.